# how to rename complex columns with agile function that share similar items

Tags: r, tidyverse, rename, tidyr

I have this dataset

```
BEZeveryextendedname <- c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B")
var <- c("B","B","B","B","B","B","B")
bar <- c("B","B","B","B","B","B","B")

Bezeveryextendedname1 <- c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B")
var1 <- c("B","B","B","B","B","B","B")
bar1 <- c("B","B","B","B","B","B","B")

dat <- data.frame(BEZeveryextendedname, var, bar, Bezeveryextendedname1, var1, bar1)
```

I would like to change column names that share similar elements. For example, the dataset that I would like to have would be like this:

```
            PrimaryA secondA thirdA         PrimaryB secondB secondB
1                    A   B   B                     A    B    B
2                    A   B   B                     A    B    B
3                    A   B   B                     A    B    B
4                    A   B   B                     A    B    B
5                    B   B   B                     B    B    B
6                    B   B   B                     B    B    B
7                    B   B   B                     B    B    B
```

can anyone suggest an agile way through this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may do

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- sub("\\d+", "", tolower(names(dat)))
i1 <- match(nm1, unique(nm1))
names(dat) <- paste0(c("Primary", "second", "third")[i1], LETTERS[rowid(i1)])
```

-output

```
> dat
  PrimaryA secondA thirdA PrimaryB secondB thirdB
1        A       B      B        A       B      B
2        A       B      B        A       B      B
3        A       B      B        A       B      B
4        A       B      B        A       B      B
5        B       B      B        B       B      B
6        B       B      B        B       B      B
7        B       B      B        B       B      B
```

Comment: thank you so much again. Your solution is pretty clean but since my column's header names are more extended it seems to be difficult to create sequence matching. Could you suggest any alternatives?

Comment: @alias Do you have any patterns in the column names i.e. either in the names or in the position?  Here, every 3 columns, it is a new set based on position

Comment: Hypothetically it should every 7 columns in my case. But don't know if it is do reliable as criteria, this is why I was using names rather then positions.

Comment: @alias IN that case you can do `library(english);nm1 <- as.character(english(1:7));paste0(rep(nm1, length.out = length(dat)), LETTERS[as.integer(gl(ncol(dat), 7, ncol(dat)))])`